# Json response transformed into new json format c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to convert a json input format into another json format by using c#.

The input format which is seen just below is gotten from a httpclient post request:

```
{
  "data": {
    "trafficData": {
      "volume": {
        "byHour": {
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "from": "2019-10-24T12:00:00+02:00",
                "to": "2019-10-24T13:00:00+02:00",
                "byDirection": [
                  {
                    "heading": "North",
                    "total": {
                      "volumeNumbers": {
                        "volume": 696
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "heading": "South",
                    "total": {
                      "volumeNumbers": {
                        "volume": 726
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "from": "2019-10-24T13:00:00+02:00",
                "to": "2019-10-24T14:00:00+02:00",
                "byDirection": [
                  {
                    "heading": "North",
                    "total": {
                      "volumeNumbers": {
                        "volume": 805
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "heading": "South",
                    "total": {
                      "volumeNumbers": {
                        "volume": 751
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wish to transform the json input to something similar to the output code just below:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "from":"2019-10-24T12:00:00+02:00",
         "to":"2019-10-24T13:00:00+02:00",
         "heading":"South",
         "volume":726
      },
      {
         "from":"2019-10-24T13:00:00+02:00",
         "to":"2019-10-24T14:00:00+02:00",
         "heading":"South",
         "volume":751
      }
   ]
}
```

In c# i have tried the below code: (also in connection with creating new class objects with https://json2csharp.com/)

```
//o1 is the json object input

IEnumerable<JToken> jTokens = o1.Descendants().Where(p => !p.HasValues);
            Dictionary<string, string> results = jTokens.Aggregate(new Dictionary<string, string>(), (properties, jToken) =>
            {
                properties.Add(jToken.Path, jToken.ToString());
                return properties;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
json = new JArray(JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("data.trafficData.volume.byHour.edges")
                        .Select(o => new JObject
                        {
                            ["from"] = (string)o["node"]["from"],
                            ["to"] = (string)o["node"]["to"],
                            ["byDirection"] = new JArray(o["node"]["byDirection"]
                         .Select(o => new JObject
                         {
                             ["heading"] = o["heading"],
                             ["volume"] = o["total"]["volumeNumbers"]["volume"]
                         }))
                        })).ToString();
```

Comment: I used the above code from Serge to solve my issue. Thank you very much for your quick reply

Comment: @Tobias, if that solved your issue, you should his answer as the accepted answer ;).

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) in this case.

My answer will be written using .NET 6 Web API model (with AutoMapper package obviously installed first).

I generated the C# classes with the tool you provided for my example.

Let's assume I have a Request.cs file as :

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
namespace Something.Requests
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class ByDirection
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("heading")]
        public string heading { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("total")]
        public Total total { get; set; }
    }

    public class ByHour
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("edges")]
        public List<Edge> edges { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("trafficData")]
        public TrafficData trafficData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Edge
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("node")]
        public Node node { get; set; }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("from")]
        public DateTime from { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("to")]
        public DateTime to { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("byDirection")]
        public List<ByDirection> byDirection { get; set; }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Total
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("volumeNumbers")]
        public VolumeNumbers volumeNumbers { get; set; }
    }

    public class TrafficData
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("volume")]
        public Volume volume { get; set; }
    }

    public class Volume
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("byHour")]
        public ByHour byHour { get; set; }
    }

    public class VolumeNumbers
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("volume")]
        public int volume { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Using your tool, I also created a Response.cs like this :

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Something.Answers
{
    public class Datum
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("from")]
        public DateTime from { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("to")]
        public DateTime to { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("heading")]
        public string heading { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("volume")]
        public int volume { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In order to handle mapping between the two type of objects, I would create a MappingConfiguration like so :

```
namespace Something.Mapper
{
    public class MappingConfiguration : Profile
    {
        public MappingConfiguration()
        {
            // TEST
            CreateMap<Something.Requests.Node, Something.Answers.Datum>()
                .ForMember(datum => datum.from, opt => opt.MapFrom(node => node.from))
                .ForMember(datum => datum.to, opt => opt.MapFrom(node => node.to))
                .ForMember(datum => datum.heading, opt => opt.MapFrom(node => node.byDirection.FirstOrDefault().heading))
                .ForMember(datum => datum.volume, opt => opt.MapFrom(node => node.byDirection.FirstOrDefault().total.volumeNumbers))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

In my Program.cs, I would then Dependency Inject my MappingConfiguration with code below, before my "builder.Build()" :

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new MappingConfiguration());
});

IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Finally, within my business class, I can do something like this:

```
var jsonRequest = "{\r\n  \"data\": {\r\n    \"trafficData\": {\r\n      \"volume\": {\r\n        \"byHour\": {\r\n          \"edges\": [\r\n            {\r\n              \"node\": {\r\n                \"from\": \"2019-10-24T12:00:00+02:00\",\r\n                \"to\": \"2019-10-24T13:00:00+02:00\",\r\n                \"byDirection\": [\r\n                  {\r\n                    \"heading\": \"North\",\r\n                    \"total\": {\r\n                      \"volumeNumbers\": {\r\n                        \"volume\": 696\r\n                      }\r\n                    }\r\n                  },\r\n                  {\r\n                    \"heading\": \"South\",\r\n                    \"total\": {\r\n                      \"volumeNumbers\": {\r\n                        \"volume\": 726\r\n                      }\r\n                    }\r\n                  }\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n              \"node\": {\r\n                \"from\": \"2019-10-24T13:00:00+02:00\",\r\n                \"to\": \"2019-10-24T14:00:00+02:00\",\r\n                \"byDirection\": [\r\n                  {\r\n                    \"heading\": \"North\",\r\n                    \"total\": {\r\n                      \"volumeNumbers\": {\r\n                        \"volume\": 805\r\n                      }\r\n                    }\r\n                  },\r\n                  {\r\n                    \"heading\": \"South\",\r\n                    \"total\": {\r\n                      \"volumeNumbers\": {\r\n                        \"volume\": 751\r\n                      }\r\n                    }\r\n                  }\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}";
Something.Requests.Request myRequest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Something.Requests.Request>(jsonRequest);

List<Something.Answers.Datum> data= new List<Something.Answers.Datum>();

foreach(var edge in myRequest.data.trafficData.volume.byHour.edges)
{
     var tmp = _mapper.Map<Something.Requests.Node>(edge.node);
}
var jsonAnswer = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

Hope this gives you an alternative.